# Get hour minute value from dropdown for initialization only inside setInterval() in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have clock rotation where minute and hour hand need set at particular angle. This angle I am getting from two drop down one for hour hand and other for minute.
But the problem is when I take value from dropdown using

```
var f = document.getElementById("minute3r");
var currentMinute = f.options[f.selectedIndex].value ;
```

both clock hand stuck at one place.
I want to take initial value of hour and minute from dropdown but only for once, after that i want to add time for both variable so the clock hand rotate like a real clock. Here is my code

```
 setInterval( function() {
          var f = document.getElementById("minute3r");
          var currentMinute = f.options[f.selectedIndex].value ;
          mins=currentMinute;
          var mdegree = mins * 6;
          var mrotate = "rotate(" + mdegree + "deg)";

          $("#min").css({"-moz-transform" : mrotate, "-webkit-transform" : mrotate});

          }, 1000 );
```

Where `mintute3r` is my dropdwn

```
<select id="minute3r" onchange="disableFunc2()">
        </select>
```

I tried to put

```
var f = document.getElementById("minute3r");
var currentMinute = f.options[f.selectedIndex].value ;
```

outside the `setInterval()` but then minute hand simply don't rotate to desired place.

How to get hour minute value from dropdown for initialization only.PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to get the current minute once, then increment it each time setInterval is called. To update the current minute while the "clock" is ticking, you can clear the interval and start again.

Make sure to set your interval to 60 seconds (60000 ms) or else your minute hand will become a second hand :)

```
var interval = -1;
$('#minute3r').on('change', function() {
    var currentMinute = $(this).val(); //get current value

    clearInterval(interval); //stop previous "ticking" of clock
    interval = setInterval( function() {
        var mdegree = currentMinute * 6;
        var mrotate = "rotate(" + mdegree + "deg)";

        $("#min").css({"-moz-transform" : mrotate, "-webkit-transform" : mrotate});

        currentMinute = (currentMinute + 1) % 60; //increment currentMinute, but keep it < 60

        //you'll also need to include your hour handling here, i.e., if currentMinute == 0, then update hour hand

    }, 60000 );
});
```

Comment: WOW very quick reply, thanks cfs. minute hand moving fine but now i am not able change it from dropdown.

Comment: @AzAh I updated my answer so that you can now change the currentMinute after the minute hand starts moving

Comment: Thanks again for helping, clock is not changing with dropdown, but minute hand started to rotate(every minute 52 degree) pls help again.

Comment: Ok its rotating according to ur code, but it is taking one minute to ratate after changing dropdown.

Comment: First Rotation of Minute hand is very strange, after setting it from dropdown, it rotate abruptly to 240 degree first time and then start to rotate normally(6 degree per minute). Also dropdown effect taking one minute to rotate one minute.

Comment: @AzAh What you are describing sounds like expected behavior. When you select a time in the dropdown, the minute hand will rotate to that value and then increment once a minute. Is that not what you are trying to do?

Comment: Here is the link [http://jsfiddle.net/xJvHA/](http://jsfiddle.net/xJvHA/)
I haven't work for hour hand yet.

Comment: @AzAh Hmm... at this point I feel like I've answered your original question. Looking at your fiddle, your next step to to clean up your code. You have methods defined twice, a mix of jQuery and browser lookup methods, and a few other things. I would suggest using what I've given you as a starting point and to use that to help you with the rest of the project.

Comment: I may be stupid, can't get it work. Please can you provide more info in jsfiddle.
Ill be grateful.

Comment: Play with it a bit more and then if you still get stuck, ask specific questions on StackOverflow. You'll get better answers if you have tried something yourself. Good luck! :)

Comment: Until I didn't play with it, It was playing with me....Thanks cfs you are a great helper.
Whole code with slight change.